# Assign a value to external variable from function

Tags: c, embedded

I've been reading here a lot but never posted until now.

My problem is that I'm stuck with some code. What I'm trying to do is receive a value through UART from Matlab and assign to a single variable that is gonna stick through the entire program.

This is the test code I'm running:

```
void start_comm(){

    //Stuck in loop untill Matlab gives signal
    // Spams character 'A' while waiting
    while (!uart_is_rx_ready (CONF_UART)){
        printf("%c\n",'A');
        delay_ms(100);
    }

    // Start reading data sent from Matlab
    // P,I,D & samplingstime data
    uint8_t p_char, i_char, d_char, samp_char1, samp_char2;

    while (!uart_is_rx_ready (CONF_UART)){};
    uart_read(CONF_UART, &p_char);

    // Print out everything out again for testing
    printf("%c\n", p_char);
}
```

This code works, everything prints out fine. What I need is to be able to use the value in p_char in other functions and I need it to be the same value as the one sent from Matlab i.e. if it's 5 then I could printf in another function and it would print a 5.

I've tried *return p_char* to a different variable but it would just revert to 0 at the start of the loop. I've also tried the following test code where I try to set the variable as static:

```
**file1.h**

extern int a;

**file1.c**

#include file1.h

void function(){

    static int a;

    scanf("%i", &a);
}

**main.c**

#include file1.h

int main() {
    function();

    while(1){
            printf("%i", a);
    }

}
```

Looking over the code, I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong with the static and extern, but I'm lost.

EDIT: Figured out the problem, it was indeed Matlab code. I needed to add a delay to it to account for the time it took to communicate with the microcontroller.

Comment: Make `a` a global variable, leave the `extern` declaration as is.

Comment: The block-scope declaration of `static int a;` in `function()` shadows the declaration of `extern int a;`.

Comment: For some reason your suggestions work with normal C but not when I upload it to the microcontroller. Do I edit the original post and upload the original code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your file1.c to read:

```
#include file1.h
int a;

void function(){
    scanf("%i", &a);
}
```

This puts `a` in the global scope. If you keep `extern int a` in your `.h` file, C files that include that header will know about it.

Comment: This won't work as OP reads into the function local static a, not the one you defined.

Comment: For some reason your suggestions work with normal C but not when I upload it to the microcontroller. Do I edit the original post and upload the original code?

Comment: Explain "it doesn't work", do you get compiler errors or runtime errors? Refer to your microcontroller's manual on how to deal with global variables. Perhaps a `register int a` might work there.

Comment: Well, the code seems fine. When I run it in xcode, the value sticks and your suggestion works for that part. But when I upload the code to the microcontroller it works partially. When I use the Arduino IDE serial monitor to send a value, the code works. When sent through Matlab it doesn't. Obviously, it's some kind of a problem with my Matlab code but I guess I should ask that question in a separate post. Your suggestion did work for it's intended purpose, so I'm marking it as the right one. Thanks !

Comment: Figured out the problem, it was indeed Matlab code. I needed to add a delay to it to account for the time it took to communicate with the microcontroller.